# mitmproxy show http on port 443 even though the request is https

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I'm running mitmproxy with a valid certificate. The problem is when I receive a GET request with the domain for which I have the valid certificate, I see in the flow.request.scheme == "http" -> True
and the flow.request.port == 443 -> True

nd not "https" as I should see.

Any ideas???

The log I see:

10.0.1.5 GET http://my_domain.com

the command i'm running :

mitmproxy --host -T -p 8559 --no-upstream-cert --cert=my_cert -s "my_script.py"

mitmproxy version 0.15

Comment: HTTPS is basically HTTP on port 443 with SSL. I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: My idea is that is has decrypted the traffic, so for the purpose of tinkering with it, it's HTTP.

Comment: in other traffic i sometimes see https

Comment: I see that mitmproxy has different implementations for HTTP/1 and HTTP/2. does that correlate with the discrepancy?

Comment: i don't think so, i will investigate it furthermore and update